# Error 406 on rails 3 application, nginx serevr

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, http-status-code-406

My application is hosted on nginx server.

Application has been buits on rails 3.

On start of application index page gets loaded successfully. But as soon as I enter my login credentials and hit submit I receive error 406 Not Acceptable.

And I can see my entered data in URL.

Comment: please add at least some relevant code and/or the nginx config..

Comment: I dont have access to these. This issue was not occuring when application was accessed from intranet however, issue started to occur once acceessing from internet.